# Sys.stdout in python cause cmd to hang when used more than 1000 times

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

I want to use `sys.stdout` to show progress. There is no percentage since I don't and can't know the max value, so I can't use progress bar library.

The problem is, I need to call `sys.stdout.write()` more than 1000 times, and it makes the command line irresponsive. It won't even respond to `KeyboardInterrupt`. The problem does not happen with print though, but I kind of want to use `sys.stdout` since it might help for logging.

Here is my code:

```
while len(self.tocrawl) != 0:
            self.__crawling()
            sys.stdout.write('Crawled {} URLs!\r'.format(self.nb_url))
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: You are using a normal terminal at stdout? You're sure, `__crawling` is not hanging?

Comment: 1000 is not a big number. are you sure that it's command line issue?

Comment: It works before when I was only using `print`, so I am sure that's not command line issue. Yup, I used my Windows command prompt